# Where is UNDELETED defined for imap?

Tags: imap

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501.html#section-6.4.5

I don't find UNDELETED defined above RFC. But it is mentioned here.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imap-search.php

I tested UNDELETED on an imap server and it works. Where is UNDELETED officially defined?

Comment: It is defined in the RFC you link.

Answer (score 1):

One page up in the search terms section:

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501.html#section-6.4.4

> UNDELETED

> Messages that do not have the \Deleted flag set.